# Triangular number pyramid in java

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, nested

I am trying to print below pyramid in Java but I want to do it using 2 nested for loops, is it possible?

```
1
12
12
123
123
123
1234
1234
1234
1234
12345
12345
12345
12345
12345
```

This is my code

```
For (int i=1; i<=15; i++){
    For (int j=0; j<=i; j=j*((j+1)/2)){
       System.out.print(j);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: I am going to guess at this. Yes, it's possible.

Comment: Consider asking a question.  Also, the code you include is almost zero percent correct.

Comment: The code is actually zero percent correct, because it won't even compile (it's `for` with a lower case f, not `For`). And `j=j*((j+1)/2)` makes no sense at all - what are you trying to achieve with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained in previous answer:

```
StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();

for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    buf.append(i);

    for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
        System.out.println(buf);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a trivial problem and it seems likely that this is a class assignment.

Here is the basic solution:

1. Generate the desired string in the outer loop by concatenating the current index to a string.
2. Print the desired string in the inner loop by repeating 0 to x < outer-loop-index-value.